# Looking for a time tourist book set in a school

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for details of a children's short story where two girls remain in school after class has finished and encounter a boy from the future. As part of his school work they travel back in time to experience the past. I remember the boy is stuck in the school temporarily and the girls befriend him. He may have been called Jet?

I do remember he uses different phrases such as 'print that' to mean 'exactly', and birds are extinct in his time.

Any ideas? This is from the late 80's/early 90's and in the UK.

Any help greatly appreciated - it's been driving me mad!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In the title of the question, you indicate that this is a book, but in the body of the question, you indicate that it's a short story. Which is it? Or are you unsure?

Comment: It was definitely a book, but a children's book so quite short if that makes sense?